# "All posts" in the category widget

Tags: functions, categories, widgets

The Category widget shows the list of existing categories. I need this list to begin with "All posts", with the count of all posts in the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

If the default category widget's interface doesn't offer what you want, there are roughly two courses of action: find another widget or adapt the existing one. The first would be outside the scope of this site, the second one is a bit too broad, but here's what you would do for big adaptations:

1. Build the [basic code for a plugin](http://wpninjas.com/how-to-create-a-simple-wordpress-plugin/) to insert your own widget in. If you know your php you can learn this in ten minutes.
2. Retrieve the [code for the default category widget](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-categories.php) and insert it in your plugin. Rename the class to prevent conflicts.
3. Adapt the code to insert "All posts" as a list item before the call to [`wp_list_categories`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/). If you're using drowpdowns it's more complicated, because you will need to delve into the [`wp_dropdown_categories`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dropdown_categories/) function.

Note that both latter functions end with filters that let you change the output. If you are sure this won't interfere with other calls to these functions, you could add a filter in the `functions.php` of your theme to do the modification. This might be pragmatic, but it is also risky. Untested example:

```
add_filter ('wp_list_categories', 'wpse250758_add_all_posts');
function wpse250758_add_all_posts ($output) {
  $count = wp_count_posts();
  preg_replace ('<ul>','<ul><li>All Posts ('. $count->publish .  ')</li>', $output,1);
  return $output;
  }
```

Comment: I wonder if OP could use the `title_li` settings via the `widget_categories_args` filter? Regarding the replacement, can't we have more than one `<ul>` from hierarchical `wp_list_categories()` output ? The fourth input argument of [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace) is the *replacements limit*, that might become handy here, to account for that?

Comment: @birgire You're certainly right about the 4th parameter to `preg_replace`: there would be more `ul`'s in the case of hierarchical display. I updated the answer to account for that.

Comment: @birgire The `title_li` trick wouldn't really work, looking at line 566 of `wp_list_categories`. It is printend outside the hardcoded `ul` that starts the list. But perhaps you could modify that again with a filter.

Comment: Then is there a way to add a count of all posts to the menu item "Blog" in my sidebar?